# What is the main difference between Asp.Net webApplication and website?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web

I would like to what is the differece between the `webapplication` and the `website`.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your title is asking one question, and the body is asking another. Can you please decide what you are actually asking here?

Comment: I need the actual difference and nothing else.

Comment: You are asking 2 things in the body of the question. Why a new page is showing as `Webform` and how to convert to `Default`. These two _are_ different from the title. Please edit your question.

Comment: @Oded-Leave that.I need only the difference between Application and the website and nothing more than that and I don't want why it is showing me as a webform or ".aspx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is [difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) between web-app projects and website projects.

Text from the MSDN :

> In Visual Studio you can create Web application
>   projects or Web site projects. Each type of project has advantages and
>   disadvantages, and it is helpful to understand the differences between
>   them in order to select the best project type for your needs. You must
>   select the appropriate project type before you create a project,
>   because it is not practical to convert from one project type to the
>   other.

Answer (score 1):

In layman language:

**Web application:**
If you can think of a site where you create an account, log in, and conduct some actual business, it’s probably a web application
So a web application is a web site that DOES something other than display content to the user.
It’s intended for user interactions and transactions, performing actual business functions, and not simply displaying information to users.
Some example of web application

GMail,Facebook,Ebay,Twitter,YouTube

**Web site:**
Web site usually use for dispaly information .They have less or no interaction with users, so we can say Websites are informational by neture.
Some example of web site

Nokia.com,Songspk

For development point of view

The Microsoft best described this on there website here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
Please take a look on following table- 
[image]